# How to deploy a Model to a different database / schema

Tags: mysql-workbench

I've got a single mySQL server.  I'd like to load 2-3 versions of the schema for testing.  I.e. load proj_dev, proj_ci, proj_stage, proj_prod from the same model project... That way I can have proj_dev for dev smoke testing, proj_ci for automated regression, etc.

I've tried numerous options under the Database tab, but they seem to all want to deploy to the same schema.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried renaming the schema in your model before each upload?